# Why Stateful bean is showing the opposite behavior

Tags: ejb, stateless-session-bean, stateful-session-bean, session-bean

I am getting different instances (on clicking Test then going back and repeating) of the Demo. I was expecting the same instance. Can someone explain what I am missing here?

**Bean**

```
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class Demo {
    public Demo() {
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Path("/")
public class Services {
    @EJB
    Demo demo;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("Testing")
    public Response testing(){
        return Response.ok(demo.hashCode()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to actually store some data in the bean, like "increment" field to see if the STATE of the bean is actually preserved or not.

Comment: Still same result.